# PHP not reading RSS when live, but reads fine at local Server

Tags: php, rss

My RSS reading script working fine at local host but at [000webhost] it doesn't work ,I double checked rss url and script for any bugs tried different rss urls but noting works

It Generates following error at 000webhost

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Document is empty in http://www.voanews.com/api/epiqq, line: 1 in /home/a999999/public_html/index.php on line 190

Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Start tag expected, '<' not found in http://www.voanews.com/api/epiqq, line: 1 in /home/a999999/public_html/urdu/index.php on line 190

 Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /home/a999999/public_html/index.php on line 197
```

My script is below

```
$xml=("http://www.voanews.com/api/epiqq");

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"

$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;


//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<$x->length; $i++) {



 $irss[] = array(
    'title' => $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'link' => $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'description' => $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,
    'pubDate' => $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue

  );

}
```

Comment: Are you using a library. Libraries will have dipendancy. Check if all of them are available

Comment: What this particular piece of code has anything to do with libraries? it is a simple use of DOMDocument

Answer (score 0):

Your host not sending requests to the external URL. For security reasons some hosts don't allow some configuration settings to be set ON permanently. So you will have to enable it when needed.